# How can I disable the bell in the Windows console?

Tags: windows, console, bell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning off the cmd window beep sound](https://superuser.com/questions/10575/turning-off-the-cmd-window-beep-sound)

I just accidentally dumped a binary file that contained lots of BEL (ASCII 0x07) characters to my Windows command prompt. The Windows console has no limits on the number of times it will ring the bell, so my computer is now in a state of continuous beep. This is using the computer's internal speaker, so the sound is really loud and annoying.

Is there a way to completely disable the beep functionality of the Windows console? I know I could pull the speaker wire, but this is a work computer and I don't want to mess with the hardware. Besides, doing that wouldn't prevent the console from locking up.

(I was eventually able to terminate the offending instance of `cmd.exe` from Task Manager, which stopped the infernal beeping.)